# Repeat image vertically depending on amount of text

Tags: html, css

I have a background-image and text on top of that background-image. However, my problem is that if I write too much text, it begins to go out of the background-image. How can I repeat the background-image vertically depending on how much text is on that background?

Also, since the background-image is quite tall, how could I repeat the image, yet have it wrap around the text nicely so that there isn't too much extra image below the text?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a div that has `repeat-y` with the background image. Like:
http://jsfiddle.net/UDJMq/

This should fix both of your problems, as it stops the image repeating where your text stops.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
background-repeat: repeat-y;
```

That will repeat the background image along the y-axis (vertically).
Other accepted values are `repeat`, `repeat-x` and `no-repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

CheckOut this [Background repeat property;](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp)

you will can  use this properties;
repeat-x;
repeat-y